# Problemas Inicialização Python 3 após exclusão de arquivos extras na pasta do projeto

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

Eu apaguei uns arquivos da pasta do projeto que eu estava usando e quando fui tentar abrir o Python novamente, apareceu esta mensagem:

Internal error. Please report to http://jb.gg/ide/critical-startup-errors

**Erro:**

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Dikson\.PyCharmEdu2018.3\config\port (Acesso negado)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtil.writeToFile(FileUtil.java:1274)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtil.writeToFile(FileUtil.java:1268)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtil.writeToFile(FileUtil.java:1253)
    at com.intellij.idea.SocketLock.lambda$lock$2(SocketLock.java:151)
    at com.intellij.idea.SocketLock.underLocks(SocketLock.java:179)
    at com.intellij.idea.SocketLock.lock(SocketLock.java:124)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lockSystemFolders(StartupUtil.java:318)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareAndStart(StartupUtil.java:122)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.lambda$start$0(PluginManager.java:75)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

---

Eu estava lidando com um `Arquivo.CSV` e ele criou uns arquivos extras na pasta do projeto. Eu resolvi apagá-los e deu nisto. Teria alguma forma de resolver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Python3 não tem problema nenhum.

Com você pode ver, o erro é de "Java", como na mensagem "java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Dikson.PyCharmEdu2018.3\config\port (Acesso negado)
 " - que alias conta toda a história do erro.

Vicê teve um erro com o Pycharm - não com o Python. Pycharm é o editor de textos  com ferramentas extras - um "Ambiente Integrado de Desenvolvimento" ou "IDE", que você usa para desenvolver seu projeto.

E, para fazer as integrações dele, ele grava metadados e anotações sobre o seu projeto - com esses arquivos ai nessa pasta que você excluiu, ou mudou as permissões de acesso.

A boa notícia é que seus arquivos de Python estã intactos - exclua totalmente a pasta do Pycharm - essa ".PyCharmEdu2018.3" - a IDE vai criar uma nova sem problemas de acesso na próxima vez que for executada.

Comment: Obrigado !   :) 
Vou aproveitar e atualizar o PyCharmEdu.